# How to close previous frames and reuse them later in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid

I have this code below. functions at forget() and remember() are supposed to remove the previous frame and grid in a new one with new label. steps should go something like:

```
step 1: f1.grid_forget()
step 2: f1.grid()
step 3: Label(f1).grid()
```

this should allow for the whole previous pane to be forgotten, together with its previous contents and pave way fr the new frame and its contents.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
f1=Frame(root)
f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
f2=Frame(root)
f2.grid(column=0, row=1)

def forget():
    f1.grid_forget()
    f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    lbl2 = Label(f1, text="Yes he's back").grid(column=0, row=0)

def remember():
    f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    lbl2 = Label(f1, text="Is he back?").grid(column=0, row=0)

b1 = Button(f2, text="Forget", command=forget).grid(column=0, row=0)
b2 = Button(f2, text="Remember", command=remember).grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`grid_forget` doesn't cause a widget to be destroyed. It only causes it to not be mapped to the screen. Since your `forget` function creates new labels but never destroys the old labels, your frame will keep expanding with each new label.

If you want a widget to be destroyed, you must call `destroy` on it or one of its ancestors. In your case I'm guessing you want to first do `f1.destroy()` rather than `f1.grid_forget()`, since you want all of its children to be destroyed. It's a little unclear precisely what you want to do, another choice would be to only destroy the children of `f1`.

Comment: According to the steps outlined in the question, replacing f1.grid_forget() with f1.destroy() is giving the error:  _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".33344848". Any other way to go around this?

Comment: @pro1991: once you destroy it you can no longer use it. That error implies that you tried to call a method on the widget after you destroyed it.

Comment: how about re-initializing the destroyed widget? f1 = frame again?

Comment: @AbdullahSaid: I don't understand your question. There's nothing stopping you from recreating the widget.